# Role-based authentication in Next.js

Tags: next.js

This is my middleware in Next.js. I want try to implement role-based authentication in Next.js using middleware.

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { Roles } from './types/role';
import {
  DASHBOARD_PATH,
  FORGOT_PASSWORD,
  LOGIN_PATH,
  RESET_PASSWORD,
  SET_TOKEN,
  WAIT_PATH,
} from './config/constants';

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const token: any = request.cookies.get(SET_TOKEN)?.value;

  const ValidUserNotAllowed =
    request.nextUrl.pathname === LOGIN_PATH ||
    request.nextUrl.pathname === WAIT_PATH ||
    request.nextUrl.pathname === FORGOT_PASSWORD ||
    request.nextUrl.pathname === RESET_PASSWORD;
  if (ValidUserNotAllowed) {
    if (token) {
      const { role } = JSON.parse(token);
      if (role === Roles.user1) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(DASHBOARD_PATH.user1, request.url));
      } else if (role === Roles.user2) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(DASHBOARD_PATH.user2, request.url));
      } else if (role === Roles.user3) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(DASHBOARD_PATH.user3, request.url));
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (!token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(LOGIN_PATH, request.url));
    }
  }
}
// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/auth/login',
    '/user1/:path*',
    '/user2/:path*',
    '/auth/wait',
    '/user3/:path*',
    '/v1/:path*',
  ],
};
```

I try to one of them. The user can not access other users' routes, but in the above code the user can access the other user's routes.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is not preventing users from accessing routes meant for other roles.

To restrict access to routes based on user roles, you need to make some *modifications* to your middleware.

See the updated code below:

```js
    // This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
    export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
      const token: any = request.cookies.get(SET_TOKEN)?.value;

      const ValidUserNotAllowed =
        request.nextUrl.pathname === LOGIN_PATH ||
        request.nextUrl.pathname === WAIT_PATH ||
        request.nextUrl.pathname === FORGOT_PASSWORD ||
        request.nextUrl.pathname === RESET_PASSWORD;

      if (ValidUserNotAllowed) {
        if (token) {
          const { role } = JSON.parse(token);
          if (role === Roles.user1 && request.nextUrl.pathname !== DASHBOARD_PATH.user1) {
            return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(DASHBOARD_PATH.user1, request.url));
          } else if (role === Roles.user2 && request.nextUrl.pathname !== DASHBOARD_PATH.user2) {
            return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(DASHBOARD_PATH.user2, request.url));
          } else if (role === Roles.user3 && request.nextUrl.pathname !== DASHBOARD_PATH.user3) {
            return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(DASHBOARD_PATH.user3, request.url));
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (!token) {
          return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(LOGIN_PATH, request.url));
        }
      }
    }
    // See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
    export const config = {
      matcher: [
        '/auth/login',
        '/auth/wait',
        '/v1/:path*',
        '/forgot-password',
        '/reset-password',
        '/user1/:path*',
        '/user2/:path*',
        '/user3/:path*',
      ],
    };
```

Comment: Not working for me, it goes back after one user login to the dashboard but when if user clicks on the browser back button it again redirects to the login

Comment: it's likely due to browser caching. To address this issue, you can set appropriate cache headers to prevent the browser from caching the login page. Here's how you can modify your middleware to include cache headers:
`export function middleware(r) {
  const t = r.cookies.get(SET_TOKEN)?.value;
  if (r.nextUrl.pathname === LOGIN_PATH)
    return new Response(null, { headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, max-age=0', 'Pragma': 'no-cache' } });
  // Rest of your middleware logic...
}`
check and update me.